# Two Select statements into one

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, subquery

I'm using MySql 8.0.23 and have two select statements. The first one reads like this:

```
SELECT w.userid,w.reportdate, t.teamname, sum(w.worked)/60 as Worked FROM apticproject.view_workedtime as w
inner join user u on u.userid=w.userid
left outer join teammembers m on m.member=w.userid
left outer join teams t on t.teamid=m.team
where reportdate >= '2021-03-01' and reportdate <'2021-04-01'
group by w.userid
order by fullname ;
```

And gives the following output:

[image]

The second select statement reads like this:

```
SELECT r.userid, sum(r.invoicetime)/60 as invoicetime FROM apticproject.view_registeredtime as r
inner join user u on u.userid=r.userid 
left join teammembers m on m.member=r.userid
left join teams t on t.teamid=m.team
where fromdate >= '2021-03-01' and fromdate <'2021-04-01' and r.invoiced=1 and r.approved=1 and charge_customer=1 and r.zeroinvoice=0 
group by userid
order by fullname;
```

And gives the following output:

[image]

I want to be able to join the invoicetime column from the second select statement to the first select statement so that the invoicetime column is shown after the Worked column in the first select statement. As you can see I have the userid which can be used as a connection point. What is the most efficient way to do this? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Use your queries as subqueries, join by common column.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to mention the version of MySQL / MariaDB you use. With v8+ these queries are easier to write becaus they have [common table expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html).

Comment: @O.Jones, it's updated

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution as shown below. In MySQL you don't have a FULL JOIN, only Union exists, and this is the syntax I have used:

```
select x.userid, x.username, x.fullname,x.reportdate, x.teamname, x.Worked,y.invoicetime
from
(SELECT w.userid, u.username, u.fullname,w.reportdate, t.teamname, sum(w.worked)/60 as Worked FROM apticproject.view_workedtime as w
inner join user u on u.userid=w.userid
left outer join teammembers m on m.member=w.userid
left outer join teams t on t.teamid=m.team
where reportdate >= '2021-03-01' and reportdate <'2021-04-01'
group by w.userid) as x

left join

(SELECT r.userid, sum(r.invoicetime)/60 as invoicetime FROM apticproject.view_registeredtime as r
inner join user u on u.userid=r.userid 
left join teammembers m on m.member=r.userid
left join teams t on t.teamid=m.team
where fromdate >= '2021-03-01' and fromdate <'2021-04-01' and r.invoiced=1 and r.approved=1 and charge_customer=1 and r.zeroinvoice=0 
group by userid) as y on y.userid=x.userid

Union

select x.userid, x.username, x.fullname,x.reportdate, x.teamname, x.Worked,y.invoicetime
from
(SELECT w.userid, u.username, u.fullname,w.reportdate, t.teamname, sum(w.worked)/60 as Worked FROM apticproject.view_workedtime as w
inner join user u on u.userid=w.userid
left outer join teammembers m on m.member=w.userid
left outer join teams t on t.teamid=m.team
where reportdate >= '2021-03-01' and reportdate <'2021-04-01'
group by w.userid) as x

right join

(SELECT r.userid, sum(r.invoicetime)/60 as invoicetime FROM apticproject.view_registeredtime as r
inner join user u on u.userid=r.userid 
left join teammembers m on m.member=r.userid
left join teams t on t.teamid=m.team
where fromdate >= '2021-03-01' and fromdate <'2021-04-01' and r.invoiced=1 and r.approved=1 and charge_customer=1 and r.zeroinvoice=0 
group by userid) as y on y.userid=x.userid
order by fullname;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care to see items from your second query that have no user records in the first, you can drop the union and the whole right join in the second half of Darko86's answer.